# Kafka Receives Messages But Fails To Add To Topic - With Setup Local Kafka VM and Minikube Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: networking, apache-kafka, kubernetes, minikube

### Set Up

Laptop with:-

1. **Kafka** in a virtualbox vm : *vagrant 9092 port forwarded from laptop's localhost*
2. **Kubernetes Cluster** in a virtualbox VM : *miniKube*

### Desired Outcome

Microservices on my miniKube cluster can fire messages to Kafka VM.
Note that this works in Google Container Engine (GKE)

### Actual Outcome

From the laptop I **can** use a console producer to send messages to Kafka VM and it happily obliges adding these to the topic. But when a microservice from the kubernetes cluster sends a message, the message is received *but* it is not added to the topic.

Instead I get the error on the microservice ...

```
    Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for generated-test-script-0
```

If I tail kafka-request.log I see ...

```
[2017-02-08 21:57:05,891] TRACE Completed request:{api_key=3,api_version=1,correlation_id=0,client_id=producer-5} -- {topics=[generated-test-script]} from connection 10.0.2.15:9092-10.0.2.2:50124;totalTime:0,requestQueueTime:0,localTime:0,remoteTime:0,responseQueueTime:0,sendTime:0,securityProtocol:PLAINTEXT,principal:User:ANONYMOUS (kafka.request.logger)
```

While in the "success" case when I simply use a console producer on the laptop I see 2 lines. 1 the same as above but I guess another ACK ...

```
[2017-02-08 22:08:12,764] TRACE Completed request:{api_key=3,api_version=2,correlation_id=0,client_id=console-producer} -- {topics=[test]} from connection 10.0.2.15:9092-10.0.2.2:50748;totalTime:6,requestQueueTime:0,localTime:6,remoteTime:0,responseQueueTime:0,sendTime:0,securityProtocol:PLAINTEXT,principal:User:ANONYMOUS (kafka.request.logger)
[2017-02-08 22:08:13,799] TRACE Completed request:{api_key=0,api_version=2,correlation_id=1,client_id=console-producer} -- {acks=1,timeout=1500,topic_data=[{topic=test,data=[{partition=0,record_set=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=39 cap=39]}]}]} from connection 10.0.2.15:9092-10.0.2.2:53696;totalTime:22,requestQueueTime:1,localTime:21,remoteTime:0,responseQueueTime:0,sendTime:0,securityProtocol:PLAINTEXT,principal:User:ANONYMOUS (kafka.request.logger)
```

### Conclusion And Thoughts

So there is no ERROR as such on the kafka server side, just on the client. My guess is that this a a network issue setup ( NAT? ) whereby the microserice in the virtual Kubernetes cluster can talk to my Kafka VM but the reply route is dropped?

The metadata is required to be returned by Kafka on the first sent message so making the batch size == 0, or "acks" = 0 doesn't really help as a hack because of the initial requirement to send this metadata back.

Any thoughts or pointers would be great as I really want to run this cluster and Kafka VM locally for dev work.